# What does <owl:Ontology rdf:about="xml:base"/> in an ontology mean?

Tags: xml, owl, ontology, semantic-web

When we see a statement like,

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="xml:base"/>
```

near the start (header) of an ontology, what exactly does this mean?

If we try to read that in plain English, this should mean something like `xml:base` an `Ontology`. But my comprehension does not go beyond that. I am missing specially the 
`xml:base` part. What role does  `xml:base` play in case of an ontology?

*(Reference: A
Semantic
Web
Primer,
second edition, 
Grigoris Antoniou
and
Frank van Harmelen, p 135.)*

Comment: That's the most XML thing I've read in my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<owl:Ontology>` says that you are starting an `Ontology` which is defined in the `owl` namespace.

`rdf:about`, the `about` attribute from the `rdf` namespace, is supposed to give a URI which will give a definition of whatever this XML is talking about. However, in this case the value is `xml:base`. This says that the subject of this XML schema is represented by the resource located at the URI *where this xml was retrieved*.

If the ontology were to contain a further `<xml:base>` element, then that would override URI; instead of looking at where we just retrieved this XML file containing the Ontology, we would instead look at the URI defined in the `<xml:base>` element.

ETA: As Ignazio points out in a comment below, `rdf:about="xml:base"` does not really work that way. Even if I have correctly interpreted what the people at Owl actually *intended* by this, what the code is actually *saying* is that the `about` attribute is the string `xml:base`, which doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: I think that's the intent of the tag, but it's incorrectly implemented. As it stands, it says that the ontology IRI is the string "xml:base", while the intention is to refer to the value of the xml:base attribute. Usually this is achieved leaving rdf:about blank and specifying xml: base instead with the actual ontology IRI.

Comment: You could very well be right, in which case I should delete my answer completely.

Comment: Your answer is not incorrect, I'd just amend it pointing out where the code in the question is... Questionable

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the same book *(A Semantic Web Primer, second edition, Grigoris Antoniou and Frank van Harmelen)* in academic research context and I think the descriptions appeared originally in the same book is necessary to answer this question, along with some additional explanation including coding cases and document references to [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/index.html), an open source ontology application builder that could be related by wider users who have not to be computer science experts in semantic web or ontology engineering.

- In *ch3.2.4 Three Views of a Statement, p66*, the `rdf:about` attribute is

  > referencing an existing resource
- As [documented](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/#ontology-meta-data) in Apache Jena, the URI of this individual of class `owl:Ontology` is by convention

  > the URL, or web address, of the ontology document itself.

Hence,

- the `xml:base` declared in `rdf:about` is definitely a URI assigned to a resource whose type is `owl:ontology`.
- the URIs in the following ontologies work in the same way:

  ```
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="xml:base"/>
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://examples/base#"/>
  ```

However there is another case:

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about=""/>
```

the empty Ontology URI works exactly in a different way, which might result in other unusual URI form such as `xml:base` confusing on a way, as questioned in this post.
[Apache Jena's document](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/#ontology-meta-data) says

> the construct `rdf:about=""` does *not* indicate a resource with no URI; it is in fact a shorthand way of referencing the *base URI* of the document containing the ontology.

Some released RDFS/OWL reasoner products can help us inspect the Ontology URI in much more detail. Here we can explain how the two cases above about Ontology URI work in Apache Jena through [an experimental repository](https://github.com/chigix/jena_stories/blob/master/src/test/java/com/chigix/jena_stories/ontology/MetaHeaderTest.java):

```java
// https://github.com/chigix/jena_stories/blob/b9af78e7c128a3e31f41bbfbafd06199099eb7f7/src/test/java/com/chigix/jena_stories/ontology/MetaHeaderTest.java#L52
Ontology baseOntology = model.getOntology("xml:base");
assertThat(baseOntology, notNullValue(Ontology.class));
assertThat(baseOntology.getURI(), equalTo("xml:base"));
```

From the unit testing snippet above, the ontology assigned with `xml:base` could be queried by a given URI `xml:base`. It implies that `xml:base` here is just a simple string representing the URI of the underlying ontology resource.

What's more:

```java
// https://github.com/chigix/jena_stories/blob/b9af78e7c128a3e31f41bbfbafd06199099eb7f7/src/test/java/com/chigix/jena_stories/ontology/MetaHeaderTest.java#L56
model.read(RDFDataMgr.open("african-wildlife.owl"), "http://ontology.chigix.com/some#", "RDF/XML");
assertThat(model.getOntology("xml:base"), notNullValue(Ontology.class));
assertThat(model.getOntology("xml:base").getURI(), equalTo("xml:base"));
assertThat(model.getOntology("http://ontology.chigix.com/some"), nullValue());
```

so even an ontology is contained in a document whose URL is different with the URI assigned on the underlying ontology resource, we still use the ontology's URI, stated as `xml:base` here, to query the target ontology.

However what if the ontology's URI in the document is stated empty:

```java
// https://github.com/chigix/jena_stories/blob/b9af78e7c128a3e31f41bbfbafd06199099eb7f7/src/test/java/com/chigix/jena_stories/ontology/MetaHeaderTest.java#L69
model.read(RDFDataMgr.open("printer-ontology.owl"), "http://ontology.chigix.com/some#", "RDF/XML");
assertThat(model.getOntology("xml:base"), nullValue());
assertThat(model.getOntology("http://ontology.chigix.com/some"), notNullValue(Ontology.class));
```

we can see:

- the ontology could be queried with a given URI that is identical to the document's URL
- the questioned `xml:base` can not help reference to the ontology resource in the document

Conclusionly, `xml:base` in an ontology is exatly just a normal URI string that could not play any special magical features.
The statement of `<owl:Ontology rdf:about="xml:base"/>` in an ontology document is to group meta-like assertions for housekeeping purposes, including

> comments, version control, and inclusion of other ontologies

, as shown in the example in *ch4.2.2 Header, p116*:

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
    <rdfs:comment> This is an ontology </rdfs:comment>
    <owl:priorVersion rdf:resource="http://..." />
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://..." />
    <rdfs:label>Ultraman Tiga</rdfs:label>
</owl:Ontology>
```

The owl documents used in the examples above are originally from the examples in the book's *ch4.3 Examples, pp.129-138*, and they could be accessed from the experimental repository as well:

- `african-wildlife.owl`: https://github.com/chigix/jena_stories/blob/master/src/test/resources/african-wildlife.owl
- `printer-ontology.owl`: https://github.com/chigix/jena_stories/blob/master/src/test/resources/printer-ontology.owl